# Want to add the key to the exploded array of the pyspark dataFrame

Tags: arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a JSON Format which I am converting it to the Pyspark Data Frame. The JSON object contains an array that I am Exploding, and Then I am Querying the Data using select.
In that I wan to do the Two things.
First:
to check iF any particular Key is Present in the array : (Which I have Done Successfully Using Infer Schema)
Second
what I want to do is if the key is not present, I want to add the key and value can be null That will Be Okay(Because then it will not give me error on select Query )

I have Tried Functions.lit()
Also Have tried many other things Use with columns array append etc but it did not work

My snippet example is

Example JSON format

```
{
    "participants": [{
            "flaggedR": "null",
            "participantId": "80d-1961-4e85",
            "participantName": "XYZ",
            "purpose": "external"
        },
        {
            "flaggedR": "null",
            "participantId": "909ba80d-1961",
            "participantName": "ABC",
            "purpose": "external"
        }
    ]
}
```

first, I have exploded it after inferring schema
df.select(explode('participants').alias('p'))
now  **I have to Find IsWrap-Up Key is Present in the array** I have it using
Done it USing
df.schema.simpleString().find("IsWrap-Up") (It returns -1 or if not present or index if present )
now if it returns -1 I want to add key "IsWrap-Up" in the array.
I have tried using f.lit()
array_contacte
or using append methods of spark But It did not

Comment: Hi @Shubham, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**`spark>=2.4`**

try this -

### Load the test data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |{
        |    "participants": [{
        |            "flaggedR": "null",
        |            "participantId": "80d-1961-4e85",
        |            "participantName": "XYZ",
        |            "purpose": "external"
        |        },
        |        {
        |            "flaggedR": "null",
        |            "participantId": "909ba80d-1961",
        |            "participantName": "ABC",
        |            "purpose": "external"
        |        }
        |    ]
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .json(Seq(data).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |participants                                                                |
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |[[null, 80d-1961-4e85, XYZ, external], [null, 909ba80d-1961, ABC, external]]|
      * +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- participants: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- flaggedR: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- participantId: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- participantName: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- purpose: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Add the `IsWrap-Up` key in each struct element

```scala
      
    val p = df.withColumn("participants", expr("TRANSFORM(participants, " +
      "x ->named_struct('flaggedR', x.flaggedR, 'participantId', x.participantId," +
      " 'participantName', x.participantName, 'purpose',  x.purpose, 'IsWrap-Up', null))"))
    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |participants                                                                  |
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |[[null, 80d-1961-4e85, XYZ, external,], [null, 909ba80d-1961, ABC, external,]]|
      * +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- participants: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
      * |    |    |-- flaggedR: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- participantId: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- participantName: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- purpose: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- IsWrap-Up: null (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Someshwar, It looks clean  let me try and get back to you:)